# How can you force an app to display it's portrait view while the device is physically in landscape orientation?

Tags: applications

Ok, please read what I am saying BEFORE you go telling me to download a myriad of screen orientation locking apps...

I have an app (Innomail) that uses 2 different displays one for portrait and one for landscape.  I do not like the landscape view.  What I want is when I turn my device to the landscape orientation physically is a way to force the app to rotate so it fills the landscape screen BUT I want the content and screen elements to display as they would if the device and app were in portrait mode.  Basically when in landscape mode Innomail gives you a split window with folder list on the left.  In Portrait on the other hand you ONLY see your email on screen and have to swipe from the left to see this folder list.  I DO NOT like this sidebar and do not want to see it in landscape.  I do want the app to rotate to fill the screen in landscape, but I want the portrait view of the app where I would have to swipe from the left to see this menu bar.

I have searched numerous different ways and looked at many many different pages, but the only solutions are to decompile, edit the manifest or code and then rebuild the app.  This is insane.  There should be a way to tell the OS I want you to rotate the screen, but I only want you to draw the screen using the portrait view.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Do you have xposed framework installed?

Comment: Rotation lock in the Settings?

Comment: This is not a rooted Device, no xposed framework or other tools.

Dan, I do not want to lock a certain physical setting or another I want the screen to rotate as I rotate the device I just want to see it LOOK the SAME as IT DOES IN PORTRAIT MODE when the screen is physically in landscape mode.  I do not want the way I view the information on screen to change as it does with more and more apps.

Comment: You said "This is not a rooted Device, no xposed framework..."
But this is my solution. I needed to solve the same problem when using Gmail in landscape, I don't like or use split window with folder list on the left. So I configured accordingly Gmail in "App  Settings" xposed module. To be honest, TWRP, root, xposed framework with modules, Tasker and Titanium Backup are mandatory on all my Android devices to be happy with them, on other side I am using all with stock ROMs. This combination fulfill all my customization needs and for many years this is my personal recipe for Android Nirvana.